# How to send text message from mobile app to ESP32 device via BLuetooth LE using Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, mobile-application, esp32, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to create a mobile app with Delphi that will send text messages to a ESP32 device via Bluetooth LE.

I am not experienced about BLE so trying to follow [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Bluetooth_Low_Energy) official document and trying to edit [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/RTL.BLEScanner_Sample) Delphi sample app (placed under ..\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\BLEScanner) based on my needs to learn the structure in Delphi side.

On the ESP32 side, I've found a DIY project on [there](https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP32-BLE-Android-App-Arduino-IDE-AWESOME/). But a thunkable app used for this project and I couldn't understand how to do same thing  (below you can find the block view of app) with Delphi.

[image]

Is there anyone who has the sample app/code that can I use for this aim? Thanks right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem with below structure;

First you should (you can do it later as well) define the UUIDs of both Service and Characteristics of the device

```
const
  SERVICE : TGUID = '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}';
  CHARACT : TGUID = '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}';
```

and define the device and its characteristic that you would like to use

```
Device         : TBluetoothLEDevice;
FCharacteristic: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic;
```

then you need to get access coarse location to get scan working (I did it on FormCreate)

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  FLocationPermission := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
{$ENDIF}
```

then, you need to execute PermissionsService

```
PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([FLocationPermission], RequestPermissionsResult, DisplayRationale);
```

**NOTE**: You can find these codes and more on Delphi sample app (placed under ..\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\BLEScanner)

after accessing all permissions (and discovering the device) you need to write to the characteristic that you want to use;

```
  FCharacteristic:= Device.GetService(SERVICE).GetCharacteristic(CHARACT);
  FCharacteristic.SetValueAsString(RawByteString('command'));
  Device.WriteCharacteristic(CHARACT);
```

**IMOPRTANT** : Because of Embarcadero disables Ansichar and AnsiString in mobile compilers. (additional info in [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#AnsiString) and [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop)) either you need to use TBytes or get Ansi support back [with this magnificent library](http://www.kluug.net/orawbytestring.php) (so you can send any command to any 8-Bit IoT device (like most of them)). Rest of them is done by MCU.